# Determine if local notification has been triggered

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

2 questions that I can't find answers:

1: How to determine if local notification has been triggered?

2: Are the local notification deleted after being triggered?

Comment: What do you mean by local notification please me specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using UILocalNotification. The modern way is UNNotification.

You can examine the contents of the UNUserNotificationCenter. Call

```
getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler:)
```

of

```
getDeliveredNotifications(completionHandler:)
```

A notification that has been delivered but not yet removed from the notification center (history) is in the second group.